# Explanation of converting exporting an XML document as a relational database using XSLT

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access, xslt

I would like to better understand the basic steps needed to a take an XML document like this Breakfast Menu...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>French Toast</name>
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <description>thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
        <calories>600</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
        <calories>950</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

And "export" it to say, an Access or MySQL database using XSLT, creating two joined tables:

- **Table**: breakfast_menu

  - Field: **menu_item_id**
  - Field: **food_id**
- **Table**: *food*

  - Field: **food_id**
  - Field: **name**
  - Field: **price**
  - Field: **description**
  - Field: **calories**

If there are online tutorials on this that you know of, I'd be interesting in learning more, as well.

Thanks.

Comment: XSLT can be used to generate the necessary INSERT INTO SQL commands for the population of the tables.

However, the provided XML doesn't have any data related to `menu_item_id`

Comment: Do you have an example of what this XSLT would look like?

Comment: Uh, is there some reason you can't export directly, i.e., link your MySQL table to Access and just append the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT transforms a document tree to another document tree. As I know there are no direct connectors to MySQL that could insert transformed data into MYSQL.

Another option might be to generate an XML that could be imported by MySQL.

`mysqldump` utility accepts --xml option that allows to dump data in XML format (so you can transform your data to the format). Unfortunatelly, loading the data from the file back is a trick that is [available only from MySQL 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing-sp). In MySQL 6.0.3 though there appears a new LOAD XML statement that can be used for the purpose.

I believe that the task can easily be solved by reading the XML with an XML-reader and inserting the data row by row using standard database connectors in any modern programming language.

**UPD**:

An xsl might look as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="breakfast_menu">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="insert-to-food" select="food" />
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="insert-to-breakfast_menu" select="food" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="insert-to-food" match="food">
        <xsl:text>INSERT INTO food(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number />
        <xsl:text>, '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        <xsl:text>', '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="price" />
        <xsl:text>', '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        <xsl:text>', </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="calories" />
        <xsl:text>);&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="insert-to-breakfast_menu" match="food">
        <xsl:text>INSERT INTO breakfast_menu(1, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:number />
        <xsl:text>);&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Any more-specific recommendations on actually transforming the data *from* XML *into* SQL?

Comment: Side note: The XSL will obviously break if any of the XML text fields contains a single quote. I'd as well recommend doing all of this in a regular programming language with some concept of both XML and databases.